# Error in function writing in R: NaNs produced

Tags: r, function, error-handling, syntax-error

This is my first time writing a function so sorry for the stupid question.

```
formula <- function(x,y){
  z <- x*(1-x)
  t <- y*(1-y)
  k <- sum(z,t)
  l <- k/2
  
return((x-y)/sqrt(l))
  
  }

formula(60.5,40.3)
```

There is an error:

```
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In sqrt(l) : NaNs produced
```

What is the mistake? I am trying to replicate this formula:

[image]

edit2:
[image]

Comment: z, t, k and l are all negative and when you try to take the square root of a negative number that is what you get.

Comment: Your function is correct, but the formula you have is only mathematically defined for 0<=x<=1, 0<=y<=1, and x and y can't be simultaneously equal 1 or 0). Otherwise, you end up with 0 on the denominator ou a negative square root.

Comment: It's not a problem per se. The calculation you are creating your function for only makes sense in that domain. The user of the function must know that and not use undefined values. The best you, as the function developer, could do, is add a `stop()` call to warn the user of his mistake in those cases.

Comment: Are you perhaps using percentages as input when you should be using proportions? Try `formula(0.605 0.,403)`, or make your function divide the inputs by 100 before it runs the calculations.